# SQL Server OpenQuery Fails with stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I've got a stored procedure which takes two parameters.  I'm trying to use `OpenQuery` in SQL Server to join on the result set of my stored procedure `dbo.TwoDrugs`.  The SQL Server is only a local machine with no one else having access.  I'm trying to do

```
select * 
from OpenQuery (AHCTW208D02,'exec [i 3 sci study].dbo.TwoDrugs ''X'',''Y''')
```

and I get the error

> *Msg 7357, Level 16, State 2, Line 1*
>
> *Cannot process the object "exec [i 3 sci study].dbo.TwoDrugs 'X','Y'". The OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI10" for linked server "AHCTW208D02" indicates that either the object has no columns or the current user does not have permissions on that object.*

I can't think of a reason why I wouldn't have permission (since I created the stored procedure), and I configured the server for data access.

When I run the stored procedure it does in fact return a result set.  Any ideas on what might be the problem with this?

Comment: If this a local machine why are you using a linked server AHCTW208D02?  If you need linked server test it in SSMS.

Comment: Are the credentials properly transfered using the linked server? You may be missing some kerberos configurations.

Comment: A linked server hits the double-hop issue for current user w/o kerberos.  To get around that, many linked servers use a specific account in their security setup.  So does it use current user (and thus Kerberos) or are you using a set account?  In the latter case the linked server account needs access.  The statement won't be running under your security context on the remote server.

Answer (score 0):

**OPENQUERY cannot be used to execute extended stored procedures** on a linked server. However, an extended stored procedure can be executed on a linked server by using a four-part name. For example:

```
exec AHCTW208D02.[i 3 sci study].dbo.TwoDrugs 'X','Y';
```

please read Remaks

Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188427.aspx